# General solution to $f(cx) = \lambda f(x)$

Tags: functions, periodic-functions, eigenfunctions, quasiperiodic-function

Which functions satisfy $f(cx) = \lambda f(x)$ where $c, \lambda$ are any constants?

The general solution for $c = \lambda$ is given in Steven Stadnicki's answer to this question: [Is the function $\frac{x}{2} \cdot (\sin(\ln{x}) - \cos(\ln{x}))$ a fractal?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2407743/is-the-function-fracx2-cdot-sin-lnx-cos-lnx-a-fractal)

There are also functions which lead to $\lambda \neq c$.

Take $f(x) = x^b$ for any constant b

Then $c^b x^b = \lambda x^b \implies c^b = \lambda $

What I am particularly looking for is a derivation for the set of functions which solve the equation, which doesn't rely on inspection (if possible).

---

Extra note:

I have thought of a graphical approach which works for $c,x > 0$ and $\lambda = 1$. Draw any function between $x=1$ and $x=c$ (or specifically, on the interval [1,c) ). [Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eIh75.png)
Now, for every point on our function $(x,f(x)) = (x,f)$, calculate the point $(c x,f)$ and add it to the graph. Now simply repeat over the segment we just added. You can also recursively add the points $(x/c, f)$ to fill in the gap between x=0 and x=1.[Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cTiSu.png)

We now have a function $f(x)$ which obeys the equation $f(cx) = f(x), x > 0$.

A plot of f(x) against $\log_c(x)$ will be periodic with period 1 i.e. the following equation will be true:

$f(x) = {\mathcal P}(\log_{c}(x))$ where ${\mathcal P}$ denotes some periodic function, whose periodicity is 1. [Image 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v6Lnp.png)

Perhaps then I could guess that the following set of functions work:

$f(x) = x^b {\mathcal P}(\log_c(x))$ where b is any constant

based off the answer we just arrived at above and the answer given by Stadnicki. This would work if $c^b = \lambda$, like before. Is this the general solution for positive c? If so, it would be nice to have an algebraic derivation, in the same vein as Stadnicki's. Also, what about $c < 0$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us suppose $c=e^a>0$ and $x=e^t>0$; the general case will be treated later.

The definition of $a, t$ above immediately leads to

$$ f(e^{t+a}) = \lambda \cdot f(e^t). $$

Defining $\varphi(t)\equiv \log f(e^t)-\frac{\log\lambda}{\log c}t, $ it is easy to see that $\varphi$ is a periodic function with period $a=\log c$.
(The definition of $\varphi$ is not ad hoc but can be found in a  step-by-step manner, e.g. by testing the functions $f(e^t),\;\log f(e^t),\;\log f(e^t)-bt$ to impose some desirable properties to the function in each step.)

Unwinding the definition of $\varphi$, we know that $f(x)$ is a function of the form

$$ f(x) = x^{\frac{\log\lambda}{\log c}} \cdot e^{\varphi(\log x)},\quad\text{where}\quad \varphi(t+\log c) = \varphi(t). $$

Your solution $f(x)=x^b$ is recovered when $\varphi(t)\equiv 0$ is chosen.

Caveat: One cannot simply take $\log$ of $f$ if $f<0$. Take instead $\log(-f)$ for this case. Finally, if $\lambda<0$, take the logarithm of $e^{i\pi t/a}f(e^t)$ instead of just $f(e^t)$.

Now, one can construct $f(x)$ on $[0,\infty), (-\infty,0]$ individually. Superpose those solutions to get $f$ on the real line. If you want $f$ to be continuous, setting $f(0)=0$ will do.

Lastly, if $c<0$, apply the condition twice to get

$$ f(c^2x)=\lambda^2\cdot f(x). $$

Solve for this equation on $x>0$, following the aforementioned procedure. Extend $f$ onto $x<0$ using the relation $f(cx)=\lambda\cdot f(x)$ and set $f(0)=0$ (if continuity is required). Then $f$ will be consistent all over the real line.

Comment: for the case $\lambda = 1$, you can also add an arbitrary constant to the function f(x) and it still obeys f(cx) = f(x).
edit: I guess this is included in the answer anyway, as a sum of solutions is another solution, and e^c = A is a solution

Comment: It seems I lost that possibility by implicitly assuming $f(x)>0$ when taking the logarithm.

Comment: Is there a way to neatly include f(x) < 0?

Comment: I mentioned how to deal with the case $f<0, \lambda<0$, or $c<0$ and also how to extend $f$ to $x\leq 0$. Though I did not work all the details out, I think the method I described solves the problem in principle.